# Unable to convert QString to TCHAR after removing unicode def

Tags: c++, qt

previously when i declare unicode, im able to do the following

```
QString myPassword = "123";
TCHAR szPassword[32];

myPassword.toWCharArray(szPassword);
```

but after i removed my uncode def
i got the following error

```
 error C2664: 'QString::toWCharArray' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 
'TCHAR [32]' to 'wchar_t *'
```

How do i convert my Qstring to TCHAR array now?

Comment: It's 2018. `TCHAR` was a 20th century hack so you could target both the Win95 and WinNT series. It's been obsolete since Windows ME was retired.

Comment: Without the UNICODE define, `TCHAR` is just `char`.

Comment: Why can't you write just `wchar_t szPassword[32];`?

Comment: Hi guys i'm using the TCHAR password for the following function WNetAddConnection2W(
    __in     LPNETRESOURCEW lpNetResource,
    __in_opt LPCWSTR       lpPassword,
    __in_opt LPCWSTR       lpUserName,
    __in     DWORD          dwFlags

Comment: @tiong, well, but doesn't `LPCWSTR` means "Long pointer to constant wide string", i.e `const *wchar_t`?

Answer (score 0):

Qt provides several methods to convert between `QString` and UTF16-LE for Windows standard:

Convert to C++ `std::wstring`:

```
QString myPassword = "abcd ελληνικά";
std::wstring wstr = myPassword.toStdWString();
MessageBoxW(0, wstr.c_str(),0,0);
```

For using `toWCharArray`, the input buffer has to have enough memory and has to be null-terminated:

```
wchar_t buf[100] = {0};
myPassword.toWCharArray(buf);
MessageBoxW(0, buf,0,0);
```

Or use `QString::utf16()` method which returns `const unsigned short*`, it need `const wchar_t*` cast:

```
MessageBoxW(0, (const wchar_t*)myPassword.utf16(), 0, 0);
```

Note, `TCHAR` is a confusing Windows macro, it is defined as `char` for ANSI programs, and `wchar_t` for Unicode programs. Avoid using it.